# падает база с различными ошибками

Tags: java, sqlite

```
import java.sql.*;

public class Bdate{
    String url = "jdbc:sqlite:d:/farcry/userDate.db";
    Connection con;
    ResultSet res;

    public void bd(String sql) throws SQLException {

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        con.createStatement().execute(sql);
    }

    public  void bs(String sql)throws SQLException{

        con = DriverManager.getConnection(url);
        res=con.createStatement().executeQuery(sql);
    }
}
```

проблема в следующем-мне нужно два метода один запрос в базу без возращения Resultset,второй с возвращением .оба эти метода постоянно используются и создается видимо несколько соnnection ,как пример вызываю 1й метод,2й ,потом 1й и база падает

> org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_BUSY]  The database file is locked (database is locked)
>           at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:941)
>           at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:953)
>           at org.sqlite.core.DB.execute(DB.java:854)
>           at org.sqlite.core.CoreStatement.exec(CoreStatement.java:80)
>           at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.execute(JDBC3Statement.java:53)
>           at Bdate.bd(Bdate.java:14)
>           at BotStart.onUpdateReceived(BotStart.java:34)
>           at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
>           at org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.generics.LongPollingBot.onUpdatesReceived(LongPollingBot.java:27)
>           at org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession$HandlerThread.run(DefaultBotSession.java:305)

если прописать con.close в1 методе через 4-5 вызовов база опять падает

> org.sqlite.SQLiteException: [SQLITE_BUSY]  The database file is locked (database is locked)
>           at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:941)
>           at org.sqlite.core.DB.newSQLException(DB.java:953)
>           at org.sqlite.core.DB.execute(DB.java:854)
>           at org.sqlite.core.CoreStatement.exec(CoreStatement.java:80)
>           at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3Statement.execute(JDBC3Statement.java:53)
>           at Bdate.bd(Bdate.java:14)
>           at BotStart.onUpdateReceived(BotStart.java:34)
>           at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
>           at org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.generics.LongPollingBot.onUpdatesReceived(LongPollingBot.java:27)
>           at org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession$HandlerThread.run(DefaultBotSession.java:305)

если прописать con.close во 2 методе полчаем сразу после вызова 2 метода ошибку

> java.sql.SQLException: The database has been closed
>           at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.throwex(NativeDB.java:478)
>           at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.column_text_utf8(Native Method)
>           at org.sqlite.core.NativeDB.column_text(NativeDB.java:249)
>           at org.sqlite.jdbc3.JDBC3ResultSet.getString(JDBC3ResultSet.java:444)
>           at BotStart.onUpdateReceived(BotStart.java:66)
>           at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1540)
>           at org.telegram.telegrambots.meta.generics.LongPollingBot.onUpdatesReceived(LongPollingBot.java:27)
>           at org.telegram.telegrambots.updatesreceivers.DefaultBotSession$HandlerThread.run(DefaultBotSession.java:305)

как быть не знаю,гугл решения не работают

Comment: Вы немного не так работаете с БД. Вам надо 1 раз сделать коннект к БД. А close делать тогда, когда вы выходите из программы. Конечно вы можете объявить не глобально(на уровне класса), а в методе(в каждом) ваши `Connection` и  `ResultSet` и там же закрывать коннект. Но много коннектов может привести к проблемам, если у вас будет многопоточность

Comment: И ещё. Лучше не отдавать `ResultSet` "наверх" а тут же его парсить в список объектов и отдавать список(а `rs` закрывать)

Comment: нашел ошибку,александр правильно написал было много соединений,я просто засунул инициализацию класса Bdate в метод updateRecived и получается как только я давал команду боту создавался новый экзепляр класса с новым соединеннием,а потом еще и методы